# Dateformat in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a date which I am getting from a REST method like.

`2013-04-11 15:03:01.0` 
 I am directly rendering in to the template .

But I want to change the date format .So i have written like this .

```
 <td>{{x.dateCreated|date:"F j, Y"}}</td>
```

Unfortunately when I am using then it is not displaying anything .

Please tell me what might I m doing wrong here .

Comment: Is the `x.dateCreated` a datetime object or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `datetime` instance for that to work. Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse your string into such an object:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(restdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way Django handles "date" formatting in templates is by parsing a string in a recognized date format. If I'm not mistaken, the string you've passed into the "date" default template tag doesn't appear to be a valid date from the Django default installation. As such, it's unable to parse and output a custom date format.

You can add additional date formats by modifying the "date format" setting.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format

Hope that helped!

Comment: No it doesn't. It defaults `arg` to the default `DATE_FORMAT`, nowhere is *`value`* tested.

Comment: Interesting, it appeared at first as if "return formats.date_format(value, arg)" would have tried to parse "value". I was hoping to avoid the datetime formatting directly and have the datetime formatted to be accessible across the site. Gracias.

Comment: Not sure where you got that idea. :-) Without looking at the source code or documentation, I'd say that `formats.date_format()` *formats* a date, not parses it.